# Can't print objects stored in HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm working on an assignment for my java class, and we just started learning about HashMaps and we have this assignment where we create enumerated data and store it in a hashmap to print out later.  What I can seem to figure out is to be able to print the elements of the HashMap. Here is my project so far:

```
public class Driver <enumeration>
{
    private static HashMap<String, State> stateList = new HashMap<String, State>();
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        stateList.put("1", State.CA);
        stateList.put("2", State.FL);
        stateList.put("3", State.ME);
        stateList.put("4", State.OK);
        stateList.put("5", State.TX);

        for(State value : stateList.values())
        {
            System.out.println(value);
        }
    }
 }

public enum State
{
    CA(new StateInfo("Sacramento", 38802500)), FL(new StateInfo("Tallahassee", 19893297)),
    ME(new StateInfo("Augusta", 1330089)), OK(new StateInfo("Oklahoma City", 3878051)), 
    TX(new StateInfo(" Austin",  26956958));

    private StateInfo info;
    private State(StateInfo info)
    {
        this.info = info;
    }

    public StateInfo getInfo()
    {       
        return info;
    }

    public String toString()
    {   
        return "";
    }
}

public class StateInfo 
{
    private String capital;
    private int population;

    public StateInfo(String capital, int population)
    {
        this.capital = capital;
        this.population = population;
    }

    public String getCapital()
    {
        return capital.toString();
    }

    public int getPopulation()
    {   
        return population;
    }

    public String toString()
    {   
        return "";
    }
}
```

Now when I try to run the program, it just terminates without even as much as a reference number for the state objects I'm trying to print.  What I think is wrong is in the StateInfo class so I tried changing some things but to no prevail.  Can anyone tell me if my suspensions are correct, or am I overlooking something?

Comment: Side note on naming: calling something "stateList" to then be a map is extremely confusing to the reader. Give each thing the name that says what it is. So preferable, just call it "states"; and maybe if there is good reason to be explicit about the type of collection; then call it "stateMap".

Comment: You do not need to call `capital.toString();` on the string `capital` in order to get a string. Just use `capital`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have overridden the `toString()` method in the `State` class:

```
public String toString()
{   
    return "";
}
```

Therefore you get no output at all as for every `value` the `toString()` method is called in your loop:

```
for(State value : stateList.values())
{
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

To be more precise: You should get 5 empty lines.

Remove the `toString()`method in order to use Java's default [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) implementation which returns the classname+hashCode() or make it return e.g. `"Capital: " + info.getCapital()`.

Comment: That didnt seem to work, i tried blocking the method, and just returning some random Strings but it still just runs and terminates.

Comment: Beware there were two toString() methods in your code.

Comment: yup, there it is.  Thank you!